# Why doesn't my GUI show 3 separate panels?

Tags: .net, powershell, border, panel

I'm basically trying to write a small GUI in powershell that has three separate panels with borders to indicate where one panel begins and ends.  However, it appears that the panels are just being built directly on top of one another.

Any assistance in this is greatly appreciated!

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Height = 350
$form.Width = 600

function buildMainPanel {

   $panel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
   $Script:tableLayoutPanel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel
   $tableLayoutPanel.RowCount = 3

   $pan1 = buildEmptyPanel
   $pan2 = buildEmptyPanel
   $pan3 = buildEmptyPanel

   $tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add($pan1)
   $tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add($pan2)
   $tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add($pan3)

   $panel.Controls.Add($tableLayoutPanel)

   return $panel
}

function buildEmptyPanel {

   $panel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
   $panel.BorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle]::FixedSingle

   return $panel
}

$mainPanel = buildMainPanel

$form.Controls.Add($mainPanel)
$form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't much in the way of auto-layout in WinForms like there is in WPF.  In WinForms you have anchoring and docking.  You could trying experimenting with docking to see if that would work. If not you'll have to manage position and size of the panels yourself.

```
$pan1.Dock = 'Left'
$pan2.Dock = 'Fill'
$pan3.Dock = 'Right'
```

Comment: I've gotten this to work before using docking, but I don't remember what I did.  Do you have any suggestions as to where I would implement the docking?  I tried on each object but that didn't work.

Comment: You could set the first panel to dock left, the last panel to dock right and the middle panel to fill.  $pan1.Dock = 'Left';$pan2.Dock = 'Fill';$pan3.Dock = 'Right'.